# Django DateTimeRangeField how to filter by lower only?

Tags: django, datetimerangefield

Let's say I have a model with the DateTimeRangeField, and I would like to filter by the `lower` bound greater than `now()`, regardless what`upper` bound is:

```
BackupResource.objects.filter(datetime_range__lower__gt=timezone.now())
```

It errors out:

```
Unsupported lookup 'lower' for DateTimeRangeField or join on the field not permitted.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing the following

```
BackupResource.objects.filter(datetime_range__startswith__gt=timezone.now())
```